# When a wish can be interpreted in more than one way, can the Dreamstone decide how to interpret it?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-84

In *WW84*, Alistair makes such a wish:

> Then I wish for your greatness

Now, I can see two ways to interpret it:

1. Alistair wish for his father to have greatness i.e. "I wish for you to have greatness".
2. Alistair wish to get his father's greatness i.e. "I wish to have your greatness".

Is there anything in the DC universe that explains how the Dreamstone act in such cases? Can it really choose what's best for itself?

Comment: I suspect 2, but it will be in tone of voice, for which we would need a reference link

Comment: Isn't it just based on intent, not wording? Your wish will come with a price, but it's not a Genie trying to trip you up with semantics.

Comment: @MeatTrademark not sure what you mean? You mean it's based on what the one who wished really wished for, in their mind i.e. the Dreamstone can read their minds?

Comment: How it turns out, would be the way that stone interprets it..

Comment: See also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/112273/how-does-this-artefact-work-in-ww84

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This helpful dialogue about the Dreamstone's origin helps us to understand:

> DIANA: *Dechalafrea Ero.*
>
> STEVE: What’s that?
>
> DIANA: A very bad God. **The God of Lies, Dolos, Mendacius, Duke of Deception.** He’s been called by many names. But if he’s the one who empowered that stone, there has to be a trick.
>
> BARBARA: What do lies have to do with granting wishes? It seems more like a Dreamstone to me.
>
> STEVE: Wishes with a trick. [The Monkey’s Paw.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw) Beware what you wish for. It grants your wish, but takes your most valued possession.

The stone clearly possesses a kind of **independent intelligence**. So given a wish with an ambiguous meaning, the stone has scope to interpret the wish along its usual principles of causing chaos, regret, and taking the most valued possession from the wisher.

This is seen even in the case of young Alistair's unselfish wish for his father's greatness. Max Lord does indeed grow in power but at the cost of becoming even more inaccessible to Alistair.

*The stone always has the last laugh!*

Answer (score 2):

Dreamstone's main motive is to create chaos. It will try to follow that goal.

That's why it allowed 2 wishes for Barbara, because it knew that only she can challenge Wonder Woman.